# How do I get JSON data from Rest APi

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am creating an object in javascript:

```
    var t = null;
            $.getJSON('http://localhost:53227/Home/GetData', function (data) {
                alert(data);
                t = data;
            });
            alert(t);
```

When I alert data, I get an object back.
When I alert t, it's null.

Can you please guide, how to set "t" to the returned data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work as expected - the issue is not that `t` is not set, it's that you're doing `alert(t)` before the `getJSON` callback is executed.  Try doing `alert(t)` immediately after `t = data;`

In other words, here's your current order of operations:

1. Set t = null
2. Call server script
3. alert(t) --> t is still null!
4. (some amount of time later) receive JSON response
5. alert data
6. set t = data

...as you can see, at step 3 't' will still be null.  Try this instead:

```
var t = null;

$.getJSON('http://localhost:53227/Home/GetData', function (data) {
    alert(data);
    t = data;
    alert(t);
});
```

Cheers

Comment: It probably won't work due to the same-origin policy (different port).

Comment: If it's the same host it should work.  Otherwise you need to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: Total non-sequiter there guys, please don't distract from op's question - this has nothing to do with same-origin, JSONP, etc.  No offense, but let's not confuse things.  Op receives `data` as expected per the post:  "When I alert data, I get an object back".  Move along...nothing to see here...  :)

Comment: Ah I missed that part.... well then.